# Merge [framerate] and [frame-rate]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

This just came to my attention when I was reviewing the suggested edit queue. The 2 tags [framerate](/questions/tagged/framerate) and [frame-rate](/questions/tagged/frame-rate) are obviously the same, so they should be merged.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There were 10 questioned tagged with [frame-rate](/questions/tagged/frame-rate), and 126 [framerate](/questions/tagged/framerate). They had the same tag wiki. The 10 is simple enough to retag by hand into [framerate](/questions/tagged/framerate), which I did. The old tag will get cleaned up eventually.

Comment: I'm going to reverse the order of that, `framerate` should be merged into `frame-rate`, as we prefer proper separation where possible.  That's done now.